# Use a dot in a class name within jquery: $('.B.Avf').toggle();

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to use a dot in a classname inside Jquery?

```
$('.B.Avf').toggle();
```

I need to keep the dot in: B.Avf classname.
Can i somehow escape it?
Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

I tried to escape it with "\" with no success.

Comment: Escape it by preceding with \\. `$('.B\\.Avf').toggle();`

Comment: Hmm.... i dont think it works. Because my filter wont work. If i change the class to something whitout a dot.. it works...

Comment: You can use the `[attr="val"]` selector: `$('[class*="B.Avf"]')`.

Comment: Don't use dots in your class names...?

Comment: @Mathletics Well. sometimes you dont have the choice!

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thank you very much. This works very well. Write this as an answear?!

Comment: Note that Tushar suggested escaping with a double backslash, not a single backslash.

Comment: @Thriggle I see, But i did copy his code and it did not work. So maby he updated it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always just use the `[attr="val"]` selector for this.

```
$('[class*="B.Avf"]')
```

The `*=` means "`class` contains...".  Since this is looking at the attribute directly and there could be more than one class, you don't want to use `=`.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to select elements that have special selection characters in their identifiers. As Tushar mentioned in a comment, you can use a double backslash (`\\`) to escape the special character in query (including both jQuery and document.querySelector), or you can use an attribute selector, as Rocket Hazmat pointed out.

Note that in CSS (that is, an actual stylesheet, not JavaScript), the selector is slightly different. You only need a single backslash to escape the special characters.

Demo below:

```js
// use a double backslash to escape characters in JavaScript query selectors
document.querySelector(".a\\.b").style.backgroundColor = "blue";

//or use an attribute selector!
document.querySelector('[class="a.b"]').style.color = "white";
```

```css
/* Use a single backslash to escape characters in CSS */
.a\.b{border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div class="a.b">My class name is a.b</div>
```